# Validation of DateTimePicker in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, validation, datetimepicker

I am trying to find out how to validate DateTimePicker ie, if DateTimePicker is null. Here's the code

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
If DTDOB.Value = Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Enter the date")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Date Saved")
End If
End Sub
```

Can Anyone Give Me The Solution.
Thanks in advance.
Note that DOTDOB is my DateTimePicker

Comment: The Value property cannot be null/nothing, that doesn't leave much to validate.

Comment: DateTimePicker.Value can't be Nothing.  see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_DateTimePicker_Value

Comment: DateTime values cannot be `null`, but they can be `Nothing`. `null` and `Nothing` are not the same thing in VB.Net when used with value types.

Comment: OK but i want to show a message box if datepicker is null. How can I?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - you can't set it to be Nothing.  The Value has to be between MinDate and MaxDate.

Comment: @MohitKamat  You're making too much of this... _it won't be null_. If you use the Visual Studio designer, VS will ensure the control itself is not null at this time. And if the control exists, it will enforce the `Value` property is between the `MinDate` and `MaxDate` you set. There _**will**_ be a value here of some kind.

Comment: Ok Sir. Thank You So Much For Your Help and Advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 If  DateTimePicker1.Value.Date = Date.Today  Then
     MessageBox.Show("Choose Date From DateTimePicker !")
 Else
     ' Your code
 end if
```

This works for me, by default `DateTimePicker` value is date of today.

I'm new to programming, don't have much knowledge but this is what i tried and it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

.Net `DateTime` variables, such as `DTDOB.Value`, are *value types*. This means they cannot ever be `null`.

In VB.Net, the `Nothing` keyword, when used with a value type, will equate to the type's default value. For `DateTime` values, this is the same as `DateTime.MinValue`, or midnight on January 1, 0001.

So you could write this code to compare with `DateTime.MinValue` instead, but I think what you have expresses intent better. If the code you have works, I don't see a problem with it. And if it doesn't work, please explain better in the question how it fails.

Comment: Actually I Already set the Min Value and Max Value in the DateTimePicker properties itself.

Comment: In that case, you are already guaranteed `DTDOB.Value` is within that range. The control won't let you set a value that is outside the range.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have misplaced the question, the DateTimePicker control always has a *Value* different from *Nothing* given when the Form is initialized. This value is between *MinDate* and *MaxDate*. If you try to set the Value to Nothing, you will get an error. By default, the DateTimePicker value is the current date and time.

An aproach could be to save the Value of the DTDOB.Value in a variable or in it's Tag and compare it with the Value you have when the click event of the button is fired.

Answer (score 1):

**(The author posted a tiny bit of code in a comment, which has since been deleted.)**

You've set the CustomFormat to a blank string to show that a value has not been selected, which is fine.  If you want to check for that, you could use the `.Text` property instead, or possibly check to see if the `.CustomFormat` is " ".

Here's a possible approach.  Once a selection has been made, change to a different format:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DTDOB.CustomFormat = " " 'An empty SPACE
    DTDOB.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
End Sub

Private Sub DTDOB_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DTDOB.ValueChanged
    ' once the user has selected a value, change the format so that a date will be displayed
    DTDOB.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yy"
End Sub

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    If DTDOB.CustomFormat = " " Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enter the date")
    Else
        ' ... do something with the Value() property ...
        Debug.Print(DTDOB.Value.ToString)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Sir. Can I store Date in a String data type instead of Date data type?

Comment: You can, but why would you?

Answer (score 0):

Made it simple and don't care of the label, it was just to display values:

```
    Public Class Form1

        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            DTDOB.CustomFormat = " " 'An empty SPACE DTDOB.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom

            DTDOB.Tag = DTDOB.Value   'Label displays the actual Value

            Label1.Text = DTDOB.Tag
        End Sub

        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            If DTDOB.Value = DTDOB.Tag Then
                MessageBox.Show("Enter the Date")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Date Saved")
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: Except the date they selected won't be displayed in the DateTimePicker since the format is still " "...see my answer.

Answer (score -2):

You code works, but is more eficente like this.

```
Dim Input As String = DTDOB.Value.ToString()

Dim dateTime2 As DateTime

If DateTime.TryParse(Input, dateTime2) Then
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime2)
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid")
End If
```

Comment: This is so much less efficient it's not even funny. Because of culture/internationalization and timezone issues, converting DateTime values to/from strings is _incredibly slow_.